# On the kernel of the Petri map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth complex projective curve and $L$ be a base point free line bundle on $C$ such that $h^0(L)=2$. Then consider the so called cup-product map:

$\mu : H^0(C,L) \otimes H^0(C, K_C \otimes L^{-1}) \to H^0(C, K_C)$

where $K_C$ is the canonical bundle. Then can we use the properties of $L$ to deduce that $Ker(\mu)= H^0(K_C \otimes L^{-2})$?

Any argument is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your assumption, you have an exact sequence $0\to L^{-1}\to O^2\to L\to 0$. Tensor  with  $K_C\otimes L^{-1}$ and take global sections to get what you want.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer.